# In CDK, how do I replicate the `eksctl create iamserviceaccount` command in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openid-connect, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I’d like to set up the external secrets operator following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/leverage-aws-secrets-stores-from-eks-fargate-with-external-secrets-operator/), but do it in CDK. I’m having some difficulty replicating the `eksctl create iamserviceaccount` step. The trust relationship from the `blogdemosa` role created by following the guide looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/<cluster_oidc_id>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/<cluster_oidc_id>:sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:blogdemosa",
                    "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/<cluster_oidc_id>:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So I think my CDK should have to look something like this:

```js
const serviceAccountRole = new iam.Role(this, 'ServiceAccountRole', {
    roleName: 'ServiceAccountRole',
    assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal(???),
    managedPolicies: [iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('SecretsManagerReadWrite')]
});

const serviceAccount = cluster.addServiceAccount('ServiceAccount', {
    name: 'eso-service-account',
    annotations: {
        'eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn': serviceAccountRole.roleArn
    }
});
```

But I have no idea what to put for any of the FederatedPrincipal’s parameters.

Comment: If your secrets are in aws secret manager or param store, you may want to use the newer [ASCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/integrating_csi_driver.html) instead. For assumedBy, I believe you want [PrincipalWithConditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.PrincipalWithConditions.html)

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the tip! The charts I'm using aren't really set up to use service accounts in this way, but I'll definitely keep this in mind for later

Comment: Basically just need to get my confidential info into a Secret, which I can then put in an environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was wrong, this is all I needed to do:

```js
const serviceAccount = cluster.addServiceAccount('ServiceAccount', {
  name: 'eso-service-account',
})

serviceAccount.addToPrincipalPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  actions: [
    'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue',
    'secretsmanager:DescribeSecret'
  ],
  resources: [
    'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:552593679126:secret:*'
  ]
}));
```

Comment: Do you really need to grant it access to all of your secrets? You can do it for each secret as needed with `mySecret.grantRead(serviceAccount);`

Comment: @gshpychka This is just for dev/testing purposes, wanted to get it up and running before getting policies set up :)